# How to convert recorded audio file to FLAC for use in Jarvis Speech Api

Tags: java, speech-recognition, flac

I am working on a speech recognition Library named [Jarvis](https://github.com/lkuza2/java-speech-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/darkprograms/speech/recognizer/GSpeechDuplex.java), which accept flac audio file with 16000 sample rate, it worked great when convert wav file to flac from this site [Audio to flac converter](http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-flac). I tried to do the same conversion through [JavaFlacEncoder](https://github.com/AlyoshaVasilieva/JavaFlacEncoder/blob/master/src/javaFlacEncoder/FLAC_FileEncoder.java) but the speech API does not accept that converted file.

This is the method in which I pass flac file and sample rate 16000

```
public void recognize(File flacFile, int sampleRate) throws IOException{
    recognize(mapFileIn(flacFile), sampleRate);
}
```

Following is the code in which I convert audio file

```
    FLAC_FileEncoder encode = new FLAC_FileEncoder();
    StreamConfiguration streamConfiguration = new StreamConfiguration();
    streamConfiguration.setSampleRate(16000);
    streamConfiguration.setBitsPerSample(16);
    streamConfiguration.setChannelCount(1);

    encode.setStreamConfig(streamConfiguration);

    encode.encode(new File("D:/test.wav"),new File("D:/testing.flac"));
```

Comment: Please give us code of your conversion, because according what you say, you get trouble with conversion, not with speech-recognition.

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: no I do not get any exception , but sometime it generate the flac file with no sound. My Requirement is: bit resolution: 32 bit
sampling rate: 16000 HZ
audio channels: 1

Comment: bit resolution should be 16 bits, not 32 bits.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Yes, you are right, but I want normalize with Sampling rate too

Comment: I have changed converter code , still it does not affect it's bit rate etc